# How to locate an exception in a method?

Tags: java, exception, sublist, skip-lists

My data structures class is working on implementing its own data structure in the form of a SkipList. The method that I am working on is subList. I've worked through most of the errors, but I'm getting an error saying that there is an exception being thrown in my `testSubList()` method. I'm not sure what this could be as I believe I've covered all errors with the input variables. Assuming that all other methods work, what could be causing this error?

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
  //subList method written by Ryan Schubert
//if a trivial case where the index is out of bounds occurs throw exception
  if (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > this.size() || toIndex < fromIndex){
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
  }
//make new skiplist to add values to
    List<E> sub = new SkipList<E>();
//run through the skiplist between the indices and add the values to sub
    for(int i = fromIndex; i<toIndex; i++)
    {
        sub.add(this.get(i));
    }
    return sub;
}  
public static boolean testSubList()
    {
      //testSubList method written by Ryan Schubert
      //make a new list and add a bunch of values to it
        List<String> testList = new SkipList<String>();

        testList.add("test1");
        testList.add("test2");
        testList.add("test3");
        testList.add("test4");
        testList.add("test5");
        testList.add("test6");
        //make a new list and fill it with sub list values
        List<String> testSubList = new SkipList<String>();
        testSubList = testList.subList(1, 4);
        //compare the test list to the sublist
        if (testList.containsAll(testSubList))
        {
            System.out.println("true");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("false");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Normally, the stack trace is pretty verbose. It contains the exact line(s) in which the exception occurs as well as the type of the exception and a message, if available. Please clarify your question since the necessary information should be present in the stack trace.

Comment: Why don't you simply post the stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

1. To get to know which line of code causes the problem, you can print stack trace of the exception which is thrown from this method.
2. Don't you think that in the first "for" loop, you should replace `toIndex > this.size()` with `toIndex >= this.size()` ? The last index of the list is `size() - 1`. For example, when you have 3 items in a list, `size() = 3`, but index of last item is 2. This means that value of `this.size()` is also out of array's bounds.